# How to solve $\sqrt{x+2}\geq x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> How do you solve the inequality $$\sqrt{x+2}\geq{x}?$$

Now since ${x+2}$ is under the radical sign, it must be greater than or equal to ${0}$ to be defined.

So,

${x+2}\geq{0}$

Thus ${x}\geq{-2}$

Now keeping this in mind, we can solve the inequality by squaring both the sides:

${x+2}\geq{x^2}$

So ${x^2-x-2}\leq{0}$

Solving, ${(x-2)(x+1)}\leq{0}$

Therefore ${x}$ belongs to the interval ${[-1,2]}$.

As ${x}\geq{-2}$, the function is also defined.

Why does the answer say that ${x}$ belongs to ${[-2,2]}$, then?

Please feel free to point out the mistakes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Be careful : When you square, the inequality preserves its sign direction if both sides are positive.**

Note that $\sqrt{x+2}$ is defined for $x \geq - 2$, so first you need to consider $x \geq 0$ and work as such :

$$\sqrt{x+2} \geq x \Rightarrow x+2 \geq x^2 \Leftrightarrow x^2-x-2 \leq 0 \Leftrightarrow (x-2)(x+1) \leq 0$$

This indeed yields $x \in [-1,2]$ if you also consider the negative values for which the derived inequality is satisfied .

But if $x$ is negative $(-2 \leq x < 0)$, then the (positive) square root will always be bigger than the negative left-hand side. Thus, $[-2,0)$ will do the trick in that case.

Concluding : $\sqrt{x+2} \geq x \implies x \in [-2,2]$.

Comment: But we usually take the intersection of the intervals that define the radical function (here ${[-2,∞)}$) and the intervals obtained after squaring LHS and RHS (here ${[-1,2]}$) and it works pretty well in most of the examples. Is there more specific 'rule' or method for such cases?

Answer (score 7):

Clearly $x\geq -2$.

- If $x<0$ then each $x\in [-2,0) $ is a solution (since negative number is always smaller than square root).
- Now if $x\geq 0$ then you can square it, so you get $$x^2-x-2 = (x-2)(x+1)\leq 0$$
  So in this case every $x\in[0,2]$ is a solution.

So finally, every $x\in [-2,2]$ is a solution.

Answer (score 4):

Once you know $x \geqslant -2$, consider first $x \in [-2, 0)$.  The LHS is defined and non-negative, while the RHS is __________.

Next, consider the case $x \geqslant 0$, where you can freely square as you have done.  Here you should get $x \in [0, 2]$ as the solution.

Now the solution set is the union of these cases.

Answer (score 3):

Let $a=\sqrt{x+2}\ge0$ for real $x$

We need  $$a\ge a^2-2\iff0\ge a^2-a-2=(a-2)(a+1)$$

$$\iff -1\le a\le2\ \ \ \ (1)$$

But we need to honor $a\ge0\ \ \ \ (2)$

Find the intersection of $(1),(2)$

Comment: $$\implies0\le x+2\le2^2$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

The inequation $\;\sqrt A\ge B$, on its domain (defined by the condition $A\ge 0$) is equivalent to
 $$A\ge B^2\quad\textbf{ or }\quad B\le 0.$$

Comment: It is a general solution. But are you sure that $B\leq0$ rather than $B<0$? I know that it does not matter actually because of union.

Comment: @ArtificialOdorlessArmpit: You mean it's one of the basic rules on inequalities…

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, we will assume<sup>**1**</sup> that $x$ is a real number since the field of complex numbers does not have an order with the usual addition and multiplication operations. For instance, if $i<2i$, then $0<i$ but squaring gives the contradiction<sup>**2**</sup> $0<-1$. On the other hand, if $i>2i$, then $0>i$ or equivalently, $-i>0$ but squaring gives the same contradiction. This means that $\sqrt{x+2}\ge x$ does not naturally make sense whenever $\Im x\ne0$ or $\Im\sqrt{x+2}\ne0$. Note that there are other orderings such as $a\preceq b$ iff $\Re a\le\Re b$ and $\Im a\le\Im b$ but since they are incompatible with operations that govern a field, we will not pursue this here.<sup>**3**</sup>

Now that we have confidence that $x$ should be a real number, we can give our full attention to solving the inequality; that is, finding $x$.<sup>**4**</sup> One approach at first glance is to square both sides of the inequality to get $x+2\ge x^2$, but in doing so, we have forgotten about what squaring means to the direction of an inequality. Since the direction is preserved only when both sides are non-negative, we have inadvertently omitted solutions when $x<0$.<sup>**5**</sup> So we must split into two cases:

1. $x+2\ge x^2$ and $x\ge0$;
2. $\sqrt{x+2}\ge x$ and $x\le0$.

However, the second case is always true, since the square root must be non-negative as discussed in the first paragraph. Thus it only depends on the interval where $\sqrt{x+2}$ is defined, which is $x+2\ge0\iff x\ge-2$, and so we have the solution $x\in[-2,0]$ in this case.

The first case can be solved in multiple ways.<sup>**6**</sup> For example, we can square both sides and rewrite the inequality as $x^2-x-2\le0$ from which we can complete the square to obtain $$(x-1/2)^2-1/4-2\le0\implies(x-1/2)^2\le9/4.$$ Taking square roots, we have $|x-1/2|\le3/2$ or $x\in[-1,2]$. And we recover the intended solution $x\in[-2,0]\cup[-1,2]=[-2,2]$.

Another approach is to use calculus. Let $f(x)=\sqrt{x+2}-x$ where $f$ is defined for all $x\ge-2$ due to the square root. Taking derivatives, we obtain $$f'(x)=(x+2)^{-1/2}/2-1$$ and stationary points occur when $f'(x^*)=0$. Solving this equation gives us $(x^*+2)^{-1/2}=1/2\implies x^*=-7/4$, which is the argmax since $$f''(-7/4)=-(-7/4+2)^{-3/2}/4<0.$$ Similarly, by solving $f'(x)>0$ and $f'(x)<0$, we find that $f$ is strictly increasing on $(-2,-7/4)$ and strictly decreasing on $(-7/4,+\infty)$. Since $f(-2)=2$ and $f(2)=0$ (by observation<sup>**7**</sup>), we can conclude that $f(x)\ge0$, and hence $\sqrt{x+2}\ge x$ only when $x\in[-2,2]$.

---

<sup>**1**</sup> We *love* assuming things. Riemann hypothesis, anyone?

<sup>**2**</sup> Citation needed. This is actually very far from easy to prove: indeed, for a very, very long time, humans did not understand what negative numbers were. So one can argue that the question of whether $0<-1$ is true was an open problem for millions of years.

<sup>**3**</sup> Extension for interest: [Quaternion square roots](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2021/01/06/quaternion-square-roots/).

<sup>**4**</sup> Here is a [visual solution](https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/886338811179716630/959400116538724412/find.png).

<sup>**5**</sup> One way to eliminate this inconvenience is to *assume* that $x\ge0$.

<sup>**6**</sup> Such as plugging it into a CAS or providing someone else with a financial incentive to do it for you. Just don't sue me after being busted for cheating... please.

<sup>**7**</sup> This can be achieved by zooming in infinitely close to the intersection on the $x$-axis on Desmos. Or just *assume* that it is $2$. Or you can solve $\sqrt{x+2}=x$, but isn't that rather boring?

<sup><sup>happy april fools y'all</sup></sup>

Answer (score 0):

You made a mistake squaring both sides without checking the sign first.  $1>-1$ but $1^2\not>(-1)^2$.

Answer (score 0):

To square both sides of an equality/inequality and obtain an equivalent statement you must be certain that both sides have the same sign (in case of inequality and both sides negative you should swich the direction of the inequality though). In your case left side is always nonnegative, therefore for nonpositive $x$ the inequality is aleays fulfiled as the $LHS \ge 0 \ge RHS$. But since the inequality doesn't make sense for $x<-2$ only nonpositive numbers greater than it satysfiy this inequality.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sqrt{x+2}\ge x$$
$$\implies \sqrt{x+2}\ge (x+2)-2$$
Let $\sqrt{x+2}=a$
$$\implies a\ge a^2-2$$
$$a^2-a-2\le0$$

Which gives $a\in [-1,2]$

`thanks to @dxiv in the comments for pointing out, I was considering the lower limit to be -1 while squaring it which is wrong as explained in previous answers`

Now $a$ is a square rooted term so its value cannot be negative, so

$$ 0 \le \sqrt{x+2} \le 2$$
$$ -2 \le x \le 2$$

Now, since $a$ is withing square root,
$$x+2 \ge 0 \implies x \ge -2$$

Combining the ranges for $x$ which we have got, we get
$$x \in [-2,2]$$

Comment: "$1 \le x+2 \le 4$" $\;$ This is wrong and just repeats OP's error, pointed out in the other answers from years ago. You cannot square an inequality without first checking that both sides are non-negative.

Comment: @dxiv I am sorry, I forgot to not include the -1. I dont need it anyways as I only desire the upper limit from this inequality. Edited.

Comment: It's still not clear what the claim is when you pass from $a \in [-1,2]$ to $x\le 2$. If you claim an equivalence then that's wrong. If you claim just a forward implication, then that's true, but in the end it doesn't prove that the solution of the inequality is $S=[-2,2]$, it only proves that $S \subseteq [-2,2]$.

Comment: @dxiv, I get it. What about I increase the lower limit from $-1$ to $0$, simply because $\sqrt{x+2}$ cannot be negative? That way I get the value of $x$ to be $[-2,2]$ as well. After all, the range of concern is only needed for my upper limit.

Comment: This is correct now, at least after you replace the first two $\implies$ with $\iff$ and fill-in the missing equivalencies between the next steps. Though at this point it becomes  basically equivalent to this previous [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3230560/291201) with the intermediate steps spelled out.